# Determine a line such that all its points lie at equal distance to three non-parallel planes.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am supposed to determine the parametric equation of a line such that all it's points lie at equal distance to the three planes, 
$$x+2y+2z+3=0$$
$$x-2y+2z-1=0$$
$$2x+y+2z+1=0$$
So far I've been able to determine the point where all the planes intersect, as well as all the intersection lines between the planes individually. However, I am unable to get much further. I've tried determining a line that goes through the intersection point of the planes and another point with equal distance to the planes, but I just end up with a horrible system of equations. I'm thinking that there must be a much simpler way of going about solving this problem.

Comment: use the formula of Point-Plane distance, calculate the distance between point ${(x_0,y_0,z_0)}$ and 3 planes, set them equal to each other.

Comment: @ZangMingJie: there is a much cleaner way to do that ! re. to the answer below.

Comment: @GCab I don’t know that I’d characterize your solution as “cleaner.”  Starting with the two independent equations generated from the distance formulas, squaring and then taking all combinations of positive and negative square roots leads to the same four plane-plane intersections as your method. Your approach has the nice feature of making transparent the identity of these planes that appear out of the algebraic manipulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did right the first step: if the planes have a common point the line shall pass through it.
However the planes do not need in general to have a common point.

The concept to apply is that, given two planes, the points equi-distant from them lie on one of the two planes bisecting the angles between the given planes. If these are parallel, then there is only one bi-secting plane (that in between) if they are distinct, or infinite if they are coincident .

Then, given two non-parallel planes $\pi_1=0, \quad \pi_2=0$ with unitary normal vectors $\bf n_1,\; \bf n_2$, the bisecting plane :
 - belongs to the sheaf $\lambda \pi_1+ \mu \pi_2=0$
 - has a  unitary normal vector proportional to $\bf n_1+\bf n_2$ (external angle) or $\bf n_1-\bf n_2$ (internal angle).

Thus, having three planes,
 - take two couples of them (e.g. $\pi_1,\,\pi_2$ and $\pi_2,\,\pi_3$)
 - determine the four (or less, if you do not use homogeneous coordinates) bisecting planes $\pi_{1,2,a},\, \pi_{1,2,b}, \, \pi_{2,3,a},\, \pi_{2,3,b}$
 - any line given by the crossing of two planes $\pi_{1,2,x}$ & $\pi_{2,3,y}$ will have $d_1=d_2\,\& \,d_2=d_3$.

In conclusion, for three non-parallel planes we have  $4$ equi-distant lines.  Less than that if some of the planes are parallel.
The above when the distance is measured in *absolute* terms. If on each plane
a direction of its normal is chosen as to measure the distance in *algebraic ($\pm$)* terms,
then the line is unique (or does not exist).

To better visualize the whole situation, let's reduce the problem in 2D.
Given three non-parallel lines, thus a non-degenerate triangle made by them, 
the points that have the same *absolute* distance from the three lines are $4$:
the $C_k$ shown in the sketch.

[image: equi_d_3planes_1]

Coming to your particular case, the three planes are concurrent
in one point: the system has only one solution $P=(1,-1,-1)$.
The unit normals to the planes are
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\bf n}_{\,1}  = 1/3\left( {1,2,2} \right)  \cr 
  & {\bf n}_{\,2}  = 1/3\left( {1, - 2,2} \right)  \cr 
  & {\bf n}_{\,3}  = 1/3\left( {2,1,2} \right) \cr} 
$$

Four bisecting planes are
$$
\eqalign{
  & \pi _{1,2,a}  = x + 0y + 2z + 1 = x + 2z + 1 = 0  \cr 
  & \pi _{1,2,b}  = 0x + 2y + 0z + 2 = y + 1 = 0  \cr 
  & \pi _{2,3,a}  = {3 \over 2}x - {1 \over 2}y + 2z + 0 = 3x - y + 4z = 0  \cr 
  & \pi _{2,3,b}  =  - {1 \over 2}x - {3 \over 2}y + 0z - 1 = x + 3y + 2 = 0 \cr} 
$$
they are of course all passing through the point P.

Then starting and taking $\pi _{1,2,a} $ and $ \pi _{2,3,a} $, the cross product of their normals is $(2,2,-1)$.
Therefore a first line is
$$
l_{\,1} :\;{{x - 1} \over { 2}} = {{y + 1} \over 2} = {{z + 1} \over { - 1}} = t
$$
In fact, inserting its generic point $P_1(t)=(1+2t,-1+2t,-1-t)$ into the (normalized) equations of the three planes
we get $4/3t(1,-1,1)$.

And you can check that you get analogue results 
with the other three lines obtained by the combination of
$\pi _{1,2,x} $ and $ \pi _{2,3,y} $.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there will be four lines where each point is equidistant to the three planes?

Comment: @JohnPeterson: yes, the lines are four for non-parallel planes and for distance intended in absolute terms. I added something to better explain that .

Answer (score 1):

First, how to build the enveloping cone of a sphere.

Given a sphere $S\to \lVert p-p_c\rVert=r$ and a line $L\to p = p_0+\mu \vec v$ with $p = (x,y,z)^{\dagger}$ and $p_0$ the vertex, their intersection $S\cap L$ is obtained by solving for $\mu$

$$
\lVert p_0-p_c +\mu \vec v\rVert^2=r^2
$$

so

$$
\mu = \frac{-2(p_0-p_c)\cdot\vec v\pm\sqrt{4\left((p_0-p_c)\cdot\vec v\right)^2-4\left(\lVert p_0-p_c\rVert^2-r^2\right)\lVert\vec v\rVert^2}}{2\lVert\vec v\rVert^2}
$$

but if tangency is required then

$$
\left((p_0-p_c)\cdot\vec v\right)^2-\left(\lVert p_0-p_c\rVert^2-r^2\right)\lVert\vec v\rVert^2 = 0
$$

but $\vec v = \frac{1}{\mu}(p-p_0)$ so after substitution we have the cone equation

$$
\left((p_0-p_c)\cdot(p-p_0)\right)^2-\left(\lVert p_0-p_c\rVert^2-r^2 \right)\lVert p-p_0\rVert^2=0
$$

Given three planes

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\Pi_1\to (p-p_1)\cdot \vec n_1 = 0\\
\Pi_2\to (p-p_2)\cdot \vec n_2 = 0\\
\Pi_3\to (p-p_3)\cdot \vec n_3 = 0
\end{array}
$$

with

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
p & =& (x,y,z)^{\dagger}\\
p_1 & = & (-3,0,0)^{\dagger}\\
p_2 & = & (1,0,0)^{\dagger}\\
p_3 & = & (0,-1,0)^{\dagger}\\
\vec n_1 & = &(1,2,2)^{\dagger}\\
\vec n_2 & = & (1,-2,2)^{\dagger}\\
\vec n_3 & = & (2,2,2)^{\dagger}\\
p_0 & = & (1,-1,-1)^{\dagger}
\end{array}
$$

with $\Pi_1\cap\Pi_2\cap\Pi_3= p_0$ a generic right cone tangent to the three planes and with vertex at $p_0$ can be written as

$$
C\to \left((p_0-p_c)\cdot(p-p_0)\right)^2-\left(\lVert p_0-p_c\rVert^2-r^2 \right)\lVert p-p_0\rVert^2 = 0
$$

Now considering $C$ and $\Pi_1$ if they are tangent with $p_1^*$ as tangency point, we have

$$
\nabla C(p_1^*) = \lambda_1\vec n_1,\ \ 
(p_1^*-p_1)\cdot\vec n_1 = 0
$$

or

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
((p_0-p_c)\cdot(p_k^*-p_0))(p_0-p_c)-\left(\lVert p_0-p_c\rVert^2-r^2 \right)(p_k^*-p_0)& =  &\lambda_k\vec n_k\\
(p_k^*-p_k)\cdot \vec n_k & = & 0
\end{array}
$$

giving four equations in the unknowns $x_k^*,y_k^*,z_k^*,\lambda_k$

Here the tangency points $p_k^*$ are located along an infinite line so

for each $k$ we have

$$
M_k(p_c,r)\cdot (x_k^*,y_k^*,z_k^*,\lambda_k)^{\dagger} = b_k
$$

should be such that $\det(M_k) = f_k(p_c,r) = 0$

and the relationship given by $f_k(p_c,r) = 0$ furnish the equidistant lines in the form

$$
L_j\to p_c = p_0+\omega_j r
$$

For the actual example we have

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
f_1(p_c.r) & = &  (3r-3-x_c-2y_c-2z_c)(3r+3+x_c+2y_c+2z_c)\\
f_2(p_c,r) & = & (3 r+1 - x_c + 2 y_c - 2 z_c)(3 r-1 + x_c - 2 y_c + 2 z_c) \\
f_3(p_c,r) & = & (3 r-1 - 2 x_c - y_c - 2 z_c) (3 r+1 + 2 x_c + y_c + 2 z_c)
\end{array}
$$

arranging and solving for $p_c$ we get one

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
3 r - x_c - 2 y_c - 2 z_c & = & 3\\
3 r - x_c + 2 y_c - 2 z_c & = & -1\\
3 r - 2 x_c - y_c - 2 z_c & = & 1
\end{array}
$$

$$
p_c = p_0 + \frac{3}{2}(0,0,1)^{\dagger}r
$$

and another one by solving

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
3 r + x_c + 2 y_c + 2 z_c & = & -3\\
3 r + x_c - 2 y_c + 2 z_c & = &  1\\
3 r + 2 x_c + y_c + 2 z_c & = & -1
\end{array}
$$

$$
p_c = p_0 + \frac{3}{2}(1,1,-\frac{1}{2})^{\dagger}r
$$

and another

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
3 r - x_c - 2 y_c - 2 z_c & = & 3\\
3 r - x_c + 2 y_c - 2 z_c & = & -1\\
3 r + 2 x_c + y_c + 2 z_c & = & -1
\end{array}
$$

giving

$$
p_c = p_0 + (-6,0,\frac 92)^{\dagger}r
$$

etc.

Attached a plot showing the three planes and the three cones associated to the three center lines. Obviously, those center lines are the sought lines,

[image]